# Silent phone without "don't disturb"

Tags: android

At least on Pixel phones, it's possible to mute the phone from settings. However, I didn't find any Android API to set the phone in this mode as you can see from the screenshot. [image] If I use the `AudioManager` using the `setRingerMode` the phone is set into vibrate mode and/or the "Don't disturb" icon is shown. Does anyone know how to use this feature?

Comment: have you found any answer to this? I am facing the same issue. It triggers the DND rather than silent mode

Comment: yes, I checked the source code and it calls an internal API. A simple app can't do it. So it's just impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've declared following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

**EDIT 2**

I've also tested it on **Google Pixel 2 API 28** and it is working as expected.

[image]

As you can see there is no “Don't Disturb(DND)” button in the notification bar.

**EDIT**

`audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0)` will let you achieve the desired functionality without "do not disturb" icon.

**Output**

[image]

**Original**

[AudioManger's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) method name [setRingerMode(int ringerMode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setRingerMode(int)) allows you to set the mode you want.

Documentation:

> Silent mode will mute the volume and will not vibrate. Vibrate mode
>   will mute the volume and vibrate. Normal mode will be audible and may
>   vibrate according to user settings.
>
> This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume
>   policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed().
>
> From N onward, ringer mode adjustments that would toggle Do Not
>   Disturb are not allowed unless the app has been granted Do Not Disturb
>   Access. See [NotificationManager#isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()).

```
/**
 * Changes mobile profile to "Silent" or "Vibrate" or "Normal" mode
 *
 * @param context
 * @param mode    - "0 - Silent"
 *                - "1 - Vibrate"
 *                - "2 - Normal"
 */
public static void chooseProfile(Context context, int ringerMode) {
  AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  if (ringerMode == 0)
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
  else if (ringerMode == 1)
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
  else if (ringerMode == 2)
    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}
```

**See also:**

[getRingerMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode())

[isVolumeFixed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isVolumeFixed())

Comment: @greywolf82 could you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: @greywolf82 In your question you've asked: "Does anyone know how to use this feature?"

Comment: yep, mute without dnd as title says and as you see from image

Comment: @greywolf82 have you looked into the `adjustStreamVolume` method?

Comment: @greywolf82 I have modified my answer a bit

Comment: @greywolf82 can you tell me what is the output after the change. Also, have you declared modify audio settings permission in AndroidManifest.xml file??

Comment: @greywolf82 I've added more info into the answer.

Comment: it doesn't enable the silent mode as you see in my screenshot

Comment: @greywolf82 In my original answer I've already given the way to enable silent mode. See `audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`

Comment: @greywolf82 and the icon you're talking about means that the phone will not ring the ringtone(i.e. silent).

Comment: @greywolf82 this answer is correct if you want to control the volume.  If you want to control the icon you can't do that.  I answered why.

Answer (score 0):

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

If you want to do the opposite (muting the phone via a toggle) without the icon appearing.  In Android, only 'Alarm' and 'Media' volume set to 0 are actually 0.  Call volume can never be zeroed, and ring volume at 0 is still audible.  It can be set to vibrate, and that vibrate function does not activate when a phone is in low-power mode unless it is a privileged app or a user has allowed it, but vibrate makes an icon appear.  Setting ring volume to actual 0, without vibrate, has the effect of making the icon appear.

It is built into the Android source and can't be overcome.  Specifically it is handled in the HAL and SystemUI, where the source for these policies can be found online here `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/modules/audio/audio_hw.c` and suitably `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/modules/audio/audio_policy.c`, with the icon display  `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb04a99/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/StatusBarIconController.java` `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb04a99/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/`

Comment: I want the icon as seen in the screenshot, if you set the volume to zero via AudioManager you see the "Don't disturb" icon, not the icon in the screenshot.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH.  Edited with the solution at the top.

Comment: ringer mode silent sets the phone in DND state

Comment: You aren't being super helpful as you aren't stating WHAT you're trying to mute.  If the above doesn't work then it will be some combination of the below:

`am.getStreamMaxVolume(0);` `am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);` `am.setStreamVolume(0, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND); `

Maybe the last flag should be different.

Comment: I don't know why it's so hard to understand, I want to perform programmatically what you see in the screenshot preformed by the user pressing the button in the red box.

Comment: Yeh, a combination of the above commands will do it, I can't reproduce it on my device through user action as you described, but the commands are available.  The API is available and you have the source code for exactly what you want listed as well.